# Pyinstaller freezes an invalid binary when includes ZMQ

Tags: python-2.7, zeromq, pyinstaller, pyzmq

I'm trying to freeze a binary with PyInstaller that includes ZMQ code. When testing the application everything works fine with Python interpreter, but final binary does not work at all.

**Note**: A different code is used here to illustrate and simplify the error:

```
    try:
        import zmq
        zmq.Context()
    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)

    print 'end'
```

Python version is 2.7.6, Operating System is CentOS 6.7 and I'm working with a virtual environment which includes the following packages:

```
    (Compiler)[user@machine test]$ pip list
    backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.4.0.2)
    certifi (2015.9.6.2)
    cffi (1.2.1)
    cryptography (1.0.1)
    Cython (0.23.1)
    distribute (0.7.3)
    enum34 (1.0.4)
    futures (3.0.3)
    idna (2.0)
    ipaddress (1.0.14)
    Jinja2 (2.8)
    M2Crypto (0.22.3)
    MarkupSafe (0.23)
    msgpack-python (0.4.6)
    npyscreen (4.10.0)
    pip (7.1.2)
    psutil (3.2.1)
    pyasn1 (0.1.8)
    pycparser (2.14)
    pycrypto (2.6.1)
    PyInstaller (2.1)
    pyroute2 (0.3.14)
    python-iptables (0.9.0)
    pytz (2015.4)
    PyYAML (3.11)
    pyzmq (14.7.0)
    requests (2.7.0)
    salt (2015.5.5)
    setuptools (18.0.1)
    six (1.9.0)
    tornado (4.2.1)
    tzlocal (1.2)
    wheel (0.24.0)
```

And this other rpm package has been installed through YUM tool:

```
    [root@machine test]# rpm -qa | grep -i zmq
    python-zmq-14.3.1-1.el6.x86_64
```

1. Case ONE: Works with Python Interpreter.

   ```
   (Compiler)[user@machine test]$ python test.py 
   end
   ```
2. Case TWO: Does NOT work after PyInstaller.

   ```
   (Compiler)[user@machine test]$ pyinstaller --onefile test.py
   ...
   12135 INFO: building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
   12136 INFO: Appending archive to EXE /test/dist/tes

   (Compiler)[user@machine test]$ /test/dist/test
   /tmp/_MEIl3jKVa/zmq/libzmq.so: undefined symbol: crypto_secretbox_open
   end
   ```

What I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be fixed by downgrading pyzmq version from 14.X to 13.X (eg: 13.1.0 has been tested successfully).

I think pyzmq includes pyNacl (libsodium) libraries on 14.X and onwards. However, I have also tried to freeze with Pyinstaller after installing pyNacl (0.3.0) in my virtual environment and I got the same error.

Does anyone knows how to do this with latest version of pyzmq?